# Is $\text{ess inf} \text{ ess sup} E_Q[H_\tau|\mathcal F_t] \ge \text{ess sup} \text{ ess inf}E_Q[H_\tau|\mathcal F_t]$ ture?

Tags: inequality, stochastic-processes, conditional-expectation

Let $(\Omega, \mathfrak A, P)$ be probability space and $\mathcal F$ a filtration. Moreover, let $\mathcal Q$ be the space of probability measures $Q$ and $\mathcal T:=\mathcal T_0:= \{\tau |\tau \text{ a stopping time with  } \tau \le T\}\text{ also }\mathcal T_t:=\{\tau \in\mathcal T|\tau \ge t \} \text{ where } t \le T \in \mathbb R$.

I would like to know why for $H_t \in \mathscr L^1(Q)$ the following is obvious:

$$\text{ess inf}_{Q\in \mathcal Q} \text{ ess sup}_{\tau \in \mathcal T_t}E_Q[H_\tau|\mathcal F_t] \ge \text{ess sup}_{\tau \in \mathcal T_t} \text{ ess inf}_{Q\in \mathcal Q}E_Q[H_\tau|\mathcal F_t].$$

My attempt is the following: It is true that

$$\begin{align*} \text{ess sup}_{\tau \in \mathcal T_t}E_Q[H_\tau|\mathcal F_t] &\ge E_Q[H_\tau|\mathcal F_t] \\
\Rightarrow \text{ ess inf}_{Q\in \mathcal Q} \ \text{ess sup}_{\tau \in \mathcal T_t}E_Q[H_\tau|\mathcal F_t] &\ge \text{ ess inf}_{Q\in \mathcal Q}E_Q[H_\tau|\mathcal F_t] \\
\Rightarrow \text{ess sup}_{\tau \in \mathcal T_t}\left(\text{ ess inf}_{Q\in \mathcal Q} \ \text{ess sup}_{\tau \in \mathcal T_t}E_Q[H_\tau|\mathcal F_t]\right) &\ge \text{ess sup}_{\tau \in \mathcal T_t}\text{ ess inf}_{Q\in \mathcal Q}E_Q[H_\tau|\mathcal F_t]. \tag 1 
\end{align*}$$
Since we took the essential supremum of $\tau$ on the left side in $(1)$ we can ignore  the uttered essential supremum in $(1)$ and get
$$\text{ess inf}_{Q\in \mathcal Q} \text{ ess sup}_{\tau \in \mathcal T_t}E_Q[H_\tau|\mathcal F_t] \ge \text{ess sup}_{\tau \in \mathcal T_t} \text{ ess inf}_{Q\in \mathcal Q}E_Q[H_\tau|\mathcal F_t].$$

Is this correct?

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: I don't recall ever seeing an essential supremum/infimum taken over a space of probability measures - how is this defined?

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to consider this post! First, I would like to define what the essential suprema of a RV is, then it should be clear what it means to take it over the space of p-measures: A $\mathcal G$-measuarble RV $Y$ is called essential supremum of a family of $\mathcal G$-measurable RV $(X_i)_{i \in I}$ ($I$ can be uncountable infinite) if
1. $Y\ge X_i$ as for all  $i \in I$
2. $Y \le Z$ as for all $\mathcal G$-mesaruable RV $Z$ with $Z\ge X_i$

We write $Y=:\text{ess sup}_{i \in I}X_i$.

Now the "index" is the set of all probability measures. Hope this makes it clear.