# Why is $\sup_k \inf_t E[X_t^{(k)}] \le \inf_t \sup_k E[X_t^{(k)}]$ obvious?

Tags: inequality, stochastic-processes, supremum-and-infimum

Let $(\Omega, \mathfrak A,P)$ be a probability space and $(X_t^{(k)})_{t,k=0,1,...,N}$ be a stochastic process.

**Question**: Why is $\sup_k \inf_t E[X_t^{(k)}] \le \inf_t \sup_k E[X_t^{(k)}]$ obvious?

**Attempt**:
I would say that the reason for it being obvious is the following:

$$\begin{align} E[X_t^{(k)}] &\le \sup_kE[X_t^{(k)}] \tag 1\\
\Rightarrow \inf_t E[X_t^{(k)}] &\le \inf_t \sup_k E[X_t^{(k)}]=:L \tag 2\\
\Rightarrow \sup_k\left(\inf_t E[X_t^{(k)}]\right) &\le \sup_k (L)=L=  \inf_t \sup_k E[X_t^{(k)}]\tag 3\end{align}$$

$(1)$ is obvious, $(2)$ is true since without the $\sup_k$ we get equality, and with it we make the right side at least bigger. We define the right term as a constant $L$ since there is nothing variable anymore. In $(3)$ inequality is true since $(2)$ is true for every $k$.

First, is this suggested proof of this inequality correct? Secondly, I can't see how this is so obvious, is there a simpler way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\sup_k\inf_t\le\inf_t\sup_k$$Is generally true. A bizarre categorical proof of this can be found as Corollary $3.8.4$, page $113$, of [Category Theory in Context](https://math.jhu.edu/%7Eeriehl/context.pdf).

A more friendly answer can be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4003803/815585).

Comment: Thank you for your response! Is my proof valid?

Comment: @scholar Your proof is not quite valid since the letter "$k$" is being overloaded

Comment: @FSrike What do you mean by "being overloaded"?

Comment: @scholar Ah, maybe this is a programming term. It means, the letter is appearing in more than one place but with a different role each time, making the expression ambiguous. It is very easy to make mistakes with overloaded letters as you lose track of what depends on what

Comment: Ah, I get your point, let me fix this real quick

Comment: What do you think, does it make things less overloaded? (btw. thanks for the explanation of this term :))

Comment: @scholar Lines $1,2$ are still overloading $k$

Comment: I am not sure why the $k$ in line 1 is confusing. This $k$ just depends on the superscript of $X_t^{(k)}$.

Comment: @scholar Your proof is now fine. I would still prefer something like $E[X^{(k)}_t]\le\sup_{k'}E[X^{(k')}_t]$ but it's not that important here, just personal taste

Comment: I see, thank you!

Comment: Just a little question, do you know a paper or book which proves the same inequality mentioned here for essential supremum and infimum? As mentioned in this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4580529/is-textess-inf-text-ess-sup-e-qh-tau-mathcal-f-t-ge-textess-sup)?

Comment: @scholar No but I'll have a think about it later

Comment: Thank you very much!